# API response JSON returns keys in snake-case and ESlint raises Error

Tags: typescript, eslint

Here is my code:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const url = 'https://api.github.com/users';

function FetchData() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUsers = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const resultUsers = await response.json();
        setUsers(resultUsers);
      } catch {
        // console.log('error');
      }
    };

    getUsers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <section>
      <h3>github users</h3>
      <ul className="users">
        {users.map((user) => {
          const { id, login, avatar_url, html_url } = user; // Error here
          return (
            <li key={id}>
              <img src={avatar_url} alt={login} />
              <div>
                <h5>{login}</h5>
                <a href={html_url}>profile</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
}
export default FetchData;
```

I get error:

```
Variable name 'avatar_url' must match one of the following formats: camelCase, PascalCase, UPPER_CASE (eslint@typescript-eslint/naming-convention)
```

I don't mind changing the variable name to `avatarUrl` but I don't know how without getting linting errors.

Comment: `const { avatar_url: avatarUrl } = user`? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrshape said, you can reassign the name of a field by [renaming it's property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#property-renaming).

```js
const { id, login, avatar_url: avatarURL, html_url: htmlURL } = user;
```

I recommend you to read the Typescript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html) for more information about object manipulation, you may learn useful tricks ;)

Comment: This or you can disable eslint rule in single file wrinting 

`/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/naming-convention */`

in the first line of the file

Comment: In my opinion, disabling a linter rule such as naming convention is not the best way to fix the issue (even for just a line). If you take this habit, you may end with a code that does not respect  linter rules at all.